# Calculating drift/browse time

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, dom-events

I am writing a Greasemonkey script (requires plain JavaScript) which requires me to calculate the drift time/browsing time of a URL i.e. I want to calculate the time for which an URL was active. It should be like this:

1. When a user clicks on some other URL, I need to store the browsing time corresponding to that URL. (`onBlur`?)
2. When a user closes a tab, I need to again store the browsing time for that URL.
3. When a user is not on a particular webpage, the browsing time of that URL should not increase.
4. When a user returns back to the URL, its browsing time should start again from 0 seconds. (`onfocus`?)

Comment: You should create it as a fx extension, and not as a gm script

Comment: Can i just ask you as to why do you say that since i have been able to very complex things using GM script. Anyhow i will be porting my GM script to a full fledged add-on...but at the time being i urgently need to finish my project and since so far i have relied on GM script and this is the last leg of the project for the time being i'll have to stick to GM script....see if you can help me out with that

Answer (score 1):

You could use the events "onload" and "onunload"

The "onload" event would start the time
And the "onunload" event would calculate the difference between the current time and the stored time since the "onload" event